# Server Error in '/' Application. in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config, web-hosting

I have uploaded my ASP.NET web application to my web host using Visual Studio.  Here is the output of Visual Studio:

```
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Publishing folder /...
2>Publishing folder Account...
2>Publishing folder bin...
2>Publishing folder Examples...
2>Publishing folder Examples/Example 1...
2>Publishing folder images...
2>Publishing folder jQuery.easySlides...
2>Publishing folder jQuery.easySlides/css...
2>Publishing folder jQuery.easySlides/img...
2>Publishing folder jQuery.easySlides/js...
2>Publishing folder Scripts...
2>Publishing folder Styles...
2>Publishing folder UserControls...
2>Publishing folder YouTube...
2>Site was published successfully http://blahblah.cp.blacknight.com/
2>Site was published successfully http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

I have checked using FileZilla that all my files are in the uploaded location and they are.

When I browse to my website I get the following error:

[image]

Here is my Web.config page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="104857600"  executionTimeout="36000"  />

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile>
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </controls>
  </pages>

</system.web> 

<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
<add key="imgFolderPath" value="~/images/Players/" />
<add key="FolderPath" value="images/Players/" />
<add key="DefaultImagePath" value="~/images/Players/photo_not_available.png" />
<add key="SenderEmailAddress" value="blahblah@gmail.com" />
<add key="SenderName" value="GaaStats" />
<add key="Subject" value="Notification Mail from Me" />
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings> 
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="blahblabh" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MyWebsiteEntities" connectionString="blahblabh" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>  
</runtime>

</configuration>
```

Does anyone know why this is???

Comment: Start by adding `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` to your system.web section so that you can see what is actually going on (remember to change it back to "On" when you have resolved the issue)

Comment: If you unsure, you can also ask your hosting provider to check full error message on the server.

Comment: I added the customErrors like you said and it needed ASP 4.0 Support.  I went into my hosting settings and changed it from 2.0 to 4.0 and it worked.  Thanks :)